# Copy Database using phpMyAdmin fails due to Foreign Key Constraints

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin, and I'm attempting to duplicate the database from one database to another (on my dev machine). I get the following error:

`#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Behind the scenes, PMA appears to be doing a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query.

Is there a way to get PMA to copy this database properly? Or, is there a better tool for working with MySQL that I should be using (preferably GUI based)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export the original DB, then import it to new DB - the SQL created in the export will have a "disable keys" directive, that will lift you over the hurdle.

Comment: Is there a better to get around this? The DB I'm working with is about 1 GB. Import and export between PHPMyAdmin Webserver and my local web bro

Comment: Best on command line if it's that big... with scp/sftp transfer if it's being moved between servers. Using phpMyAdmin with the GUI overhead, timeouts and upload size limits will be problematic.